How to Load Sentinel NVDI Layer on Google Maps Based on Selected Field Coordinates
I'm working on a web application where users can interact with a Google Map. The map is already loaded, and users can select a field which is then added to a sidebar. When a user clicks on a field in the sidebar, I need to fetch and display a Sentinel NVDI layer for that field based on its coordinates.
Here’s what I have so far:
The map and sidebar are set up correctly.
Users can select a field, which updates the sidebar.
I want to add functionality such that when a user clicks on a field in the sidebar, a Sentinel NVDI layer is fetched and displayed on the map, covering the area of the selected field. The rest of the map should remain unchanged.
  const fetchSentinelLayer = async (coordinates) => {
    try {
      const sentinelClientId= <key>;
      const sentinelClientSecret = <key>";
      
      // Fetch access token using client credentials
      const tokenResponse = await fetch(
        "https://services.sentinel-hub.com/oauth/token",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
          body: new URLSearchParams({
            client_id: sentinelClientId,
            client_secret: sentinelClientSecret,
            grant_type: "client_credentials",
          }),
        }
      );

      const tokenData = await tokenResponse.json();
      const accessToken = tokenData.access_token;

      // Alert when the access token is fetched
      alert("Access token fetched!");

      console.log(accessToken);
      // Fetch the Sentinel layer
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://services.sentinel-hub.com/ogc/wms/<key>",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, // Use the access token
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            service: "WMS",
            request: "GetMap",
            layers: "WMS",
            bbox: coordinates.flatMap((coord) => [coord.lng, coord.lat]),
            width: 256,
            height: 256,
            format: "image/png",
            transparent: true,
          }),
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        const result = await response.blob();
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(result);
        addLayerToMap(imageUrl);
        // Alert when the Sentinel layer is fetched
        alert("Sentinel layer fetched and added to the map!");
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to fetch Sentinel layer");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  const addLayerToMap = (imageUrl) => {
    const layer = new window.google.maps.GroundOverlay(imageUrl, {
      bounds: {
        north: 33.639777,
        south: 33.629777,
        east: 72.995718,
        west: 72.975718,
      },
    });
    layer.setMap(map);
  };

Issue:
I am encountering the following error:
POST https://services.sentinel-hub.com/oauth/token net::ERR_FAILED

Additionally, I get a JSON parsing error when trying to handle the response from the token fetch request:
Error fetching Sentinel credentials: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Questions:

How can I properly handle the access token fetch to avoid the net::ERR_FAILED error?
What could be causing the JSON parsing error, and how can I resolve it?
Is there a better way to ensure that the Sentinel NVDI layer is correctly fetched and displayed on the map based on the field coordinates?

